# my facebook app wont login from chrome

Tags: facebook

the first time user tries on chrome they get facebook popup saying my app wants to access following permissions.. the user click okay, and the popup goes away but then authResponse is not fired and if they try to log in again there is a quick popup that is blank and goes away but nothing happens?

Comment: A very brief description and no code is not likely to receive any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a similar issue where in chrome the js-sdk will give me the momentary fb popup, but doesnt actually seem to log the user in or recognize the user being logged in/authorized.

Go into chrome settings - advanced settings; Under privacy click "content settings". Check if the "Block 3rd party cookies and site data" is checked.  In my case I think I've narrowed my issue down to that setting.

If you have it enabled, try disabling it to see if that fixes it for you... although that's really just a diagnostic step, it's not a resolution since you would still have users who have that setting enabled.

I'm trying to determine the workaround if any.. possibly involving the use of fb login flow "for web" (ie not using their sdk and thereby potentially avoiding the use of 3rd-party cookies)

here's my post on my version of this issue... can facebook javascript/php SDK's "talk" to each other if 3rd-party cookies are disabled? facebook->getUser() returns 0

Comment: yes, thank you that setting makes it work. we only have few users s will tell them to uncheck that setting